# PoEAA: что все-таки должно быть в коде?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Книга ["Шаблоны корпоративных приложений"](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0579-6.html), издание 2012 года. Вопрос по примерам кода в главе, посвященной преобразователю данных (*Data Mapper*).

Один и тот же метод *load()* класса **AbstractMapper** в главе приведен трижды с одним изменением, которое сбивает с толку.

Итак, код на странице 194:

```
protected DomainObject load(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
{
    Long id = new Long(rs.getLong(1));

    if (loadedMap.containsKey(id))
        return (DomainObject) loadedMap.get(id);

    DomainObject result = doLoad(id, rs);
    loadedMap.put(id, result);
    return result;
}
```

Этот же метод (но с "id" вместо единицы) на странице 200:

```
protected DomainObject load(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
{
    Long id = new Long(rs.getLong("id"));
    //...
}
```

На странице 201 (в пределах книжного разворота) опять единица:

```
protected DomainObject load(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
{
    Long id = new Long(rs.getLong(1));
    //...
}
```

Что все-таки должно передаваться методу *rs.getLong()*?

Comment: Метод ResultSet.getLong() как бы описан в документации на java.sql, и там как бы расписано, какие аргументы он принимает...

Comment: Хорошо. Правильно ли я понимаю, что 1 в данных примерах - это [магическое число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Магическое_число_(программирование))?

Comment: Можно и так сказать. Но это вопрос как минимум спорный: числа 0, 1 и 2 часто считается допустимым использовать в явном виде, особенно в самоочевидных контекстах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что все-таки должно передаваться методу rs.getLong()?

То, что нужно в каждом конкретном контексте. Ибо:

**ResultSet Members**

...

**getLong(int)** Get the value of a column in the current row as a Java long.

**getLong(String)** Get the value of a column in the current row as a Java long.

...

Answer (score 0):

Методы для получения значений колонки для указанного ряда, геттеры (getBoolean(), getLong(), getInt() и пр.), могут принимать либо индекс (порядковый номер) колонки в целочисленном виде, либо строку, которая соответствует названию колонки.

В данном примере, у Фаулера, логично предположить, что у него просто колонка "id" идет первой по счету, т.е. имеет индекс 1. Соответственно, он в своих примерах эти записи рассматривает как тождественные и взаимозаменяемые.

Comment: Игорь, я бы не спешил с фразами "логично предположить", "рассматривает как тождественные". Во-первых, в книге есть реальные несостыковки и проблемы по коду. Во-вторых, книга - переводная и это еще один источник потенциальных ошибок. Фаулер, конечно, крутой, но вот использование магических чисел в коде посвященной паттернам, — так себе решение.

Comment: Я б не сказал, что 1 здесь - magic number. С тем же "успехом" можно придраться и к `"id"`.

Comment: код в книге - это иллюстрации к теории, а не примеры реального кода, готового к использованию, и не заготовки, от которых стоит плясать

Comment: 1. Про магические числа: даже если формально это не оно, то очень близкое и менее юзер-френдли решение. 2. Насчет "придраться к ID": в том и посыл вопроса - а чего данные пляшут? 3. Про роль кода в книге - не согласен: он тут именно для того, чтобы было от чего плясать.

Comment: вы всерьез рассматриваете приведенный в книге код, как пример реально рабочего для продакшн решения, которое достаточно хорошенько прочитать, подменить под свои таблицы/константы/сущности, чуть-чуть переписать и использовать в бою? это не более чем примеры, которые иллюстрируют описаный в главах материал в ознакомительных целях, из них достаточно уловить идею, а не дотошно изучать реализацию

Comment: Игорь, само собой, я так не считаю. Что, однако, не мешает мне дотошно изучать реализацию, особенно если книга преподносится как маст хэв и маст рид (и не принимайте это на свой счет — книгу я начал изучать еще до вашей рекомендации и именно недостаток конкретики в ней побудил меня искать другие источники информации).

Comment: Поймите правильно, дотошно изучать реализацию - это хорошо, проблема в том, что приводимая в книге реализация весьма схематичная по причине того, что она должна лишь проилюстрировать теоретический материал, а не является готовым решением и best practices, и именно так она там и позиционируется. Диаграммы взаимодействия классов из книги являются гораздо более ценным кандидатом для дотошного изучения.